# Admin-on-rest: How can I set environment variables?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Does admin-on-rest support dotenv style environment variables *without* ejecting?

I'm trying to use environment variables as described [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) but they aren't appearing in my `process.env`

Comment: Did you actually export the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. I wasn't prefixing the variables with `REACT_APP_` as described [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables)